# Subsetting with for loop and creating multiple data frames from that loop.

Tags: r, for-loop, dataframe, subset

I am trying to create a for loop that subsets a data frame. Here is the data:

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  Number = c(45,62,27,34,37,55,40),
  Day = c("Mon", "Tues", "Wed", "Thurs", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"),
  Time = c("1pm", "4pm", "3pm", "2pm", "4pm", "1pm", "2pm"),
  City = c("Chicago", "New York", "LA", "Miami", "San Diego", "Austin", "Dallas"))
```

The function I am trying is:

```
allNames<-variable.names(df1)


for (i in allNames){
  if(any(variable.names(df1)== i)){
    i <- df1[,c(i)]
  }
}
```

Basically I am trying to subset the data file so the end result would be 4 data sets each with one variable from df1 and each subsetted data set would be named the variable that it represents. It would look like this for each variable from df1

```
 Number
1     45
2     62
3     27
4     34
5     37
6     55
7     40

    Day
1   Mon
2  Tues
3   Wed
4 Thurs
5   Fri
6   Sat
7   Sun
```

Thanks!

Comment: I think I understand what you are asking, but I cannot conceive of *why* this might be useful. For instance, having a variable named `Number` that is a `data.frame` of 1 column seems like it offers no value (in fact, added complexity) over `df1["Number"]`. Perhaps if you describe why you think this is necessary, we can better advise on how to do it. (Typically, dealing with multiple similar frames is best done within a `list` of frames, not individual variables.)

Comment: @r2evans ... my thoughts exactly! This is an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). OP is giving us his Y solution to an X problem he doesn't explain. Likely he needs such a format for a reason and it can be done in a different way if OP can provide us a fuller background.

Comment: This is just a sample made up dataset to get to the essence of what I am trying to do. The real dataset is much larger and variables are unrelated to this sample. I just need to understand if it is possible to subset and create multiple separate data frames from a for loop. Nothing more nothing less. Yes, I can solve my own problem without a loop but it takes more lines of code of tedious work.

Comment: No one is commenting on the size of your data or the content of the variables. Of course they're just examples. We're commenting that there is almost never a good reason for doing this. **If you share with us the *next step* in your process, we can almost certainly show you an easier, less tedious way that takes fewer lines of code** than the approach you propose in your question. Otherwise Ross's answer basically gets you what you want.

Comment: Jake, there's no reason for hostility. Often questions which suggest specifically (but unintentionally) circumventing optimizations in R are based on misunderstanding, lack of experience, or something else. It is often helpful to ask "why" so that the underlying need can be solved in a way that is more tuned to R's efficiencies. Though I think the answer Ross provided is "not best-practice" from an R viewpoint, it meets your needs, so please accept it and move on. Otherwise, understand that our "why" question is based on our willingness to help you. Ditto @Gregor.

Comment: @r2 Please point out where my comment is hostile? I provided all the information needed to answer the question I asked. If you cannot answer it no big deal. I appreciate all the help I have gotten on this site.

Comment: @Jake, my answer appears to suffice for your specific needs, but I would encourage you to describe the wider problem if you feel you can. I know when I was starting out I was looking for a similar approach, and I found `assign` to be very helpful, but over time I have changed my programming approach, rarely make use of `assign`, and feel better off by not doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
for (i in allNames) {
  if(any(variable.names(df1)== i)) {assign(i, df1[,c(i)])}
}
```

Comment: @Parfait I'm not sure that achieves what the user asked for. But yes that's another perfectly valid approach.

Comment: @Parfait, I think your trick should use `sapply(..., simplify=FALSE)` so that it preserves names. And then you can further simplify the whole expression as `as.list(df1)`, because that's all that is happening (merely changing the class from `data.frame` to `list`, nearly a no-op). Which argues the original question: *why?*

Comment: @r2evans do you know how to solve the problem or not? The why is irrelevant, I am asking a specific question to answer a specific problem. If you know how to solve it feel free to share if not don't answer. I asked exactly what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Just use `df1[,c(i), drop = FALSE]` to keep it a data frame.